# How to run multiple user on each iteration in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, stress-testing

I have 5 users and 20 sampler, I want to run one user on each itertion. Each sampler is dependent on others. So, If one user login there data will be passed to the other samplers inside the iteration until they logout. I want to run it as 100 threads using one user for each iteration. Help me how to run this?

[My thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xR3y.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to do anything (maybe apart from [correlating](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) dynamic parameters)

1. JMeter starts all threads (virtual users) defined in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) within the bounds of the ramp-up period. In your case after 1st second there will be 25 users and after 2nd second there will be 50 users
2. Once started each user begins executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [logic controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are local to the thread, the same applies to the authentication context coming from i.e. [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and others.
3. When there are no more Samplers to execute and loops to iterate the thread is being shut down
4. When there are no more running threads the test will end.